# ggplot axes limit (discrete/continuous data issues)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a ggplot graph and am having difficulty getting the axes to be correct.  I wish to widen them from those that ggplot originally gave.  This is my data:

```
Date <- c("07/12/2012 05:00:00", "07/12/2012 06:00:00", "07/12/2012 07:00:00",
      "07/12/2012 08:00:00","07/12/2012 10:00:00","07/12/2012 11:00:00")
Date <- strptime(Date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
Counts <- c("0","3","10","6","5","4")
Counts <- as.numeric(Counts)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Counts,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date, y=Counts)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1))
g + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15))
g + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(04:00, 13:00))
g
```

I think the problem lies with continuous versus discrete data (particularly how to deal with the Date variable), but I am struggling to repair the code.  Any help would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you see my edited answer here, for the x-axis ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814216/error-message-plotting-timeseries-with-ggplot2

Comment: Many thanks @jiba.  That's great (sorry, I didn't see that, I must be going crazy), but is there a way of taking out the date.  I wish to run this code on > 1000 files and so the specific day won't be the same.

Comment: @KT_1 it sounds like you need to call `scale_x_continuous` but leave the `limits` to be the default, instead use the `expand` argument. See the expand entry [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/continuous_scale.html).