# Plotting temperature and time (m/d/y h:m:s AM/PM) from 3 csv files in R

Tags: r, class, datetime, csv

I am a beginner R user and would need to do something that is wrecking my head. I have 3 csv files, each with 2 columns: 1 for time (in the for of "month/day/year hour:minute:second am/pm") and 1 for temperatures. The times of the measurements are different for the 3 files.
The first problem I get and I don't seem to overcome is that when opening the csv file, R does not recognise the "Time" column as time (it attributes the class of "character").

This is how the file looks like (the file's name is Noble2):

```
Time    Temp
1   08/20/14 02:05:02 PM    17.034
2   08/20/14 02:35:02 PM    16.749
3   08/20/14 03:05:02 PM    16.963
4   08/20/14 03:35:02 PM    16.820
5   08/20/14 04:05:02 PM    16.963
6   08/20/14 04:35:02 PM    17.153
7   08/20/14 05:05:02 PM    16.249
8   08/20/14 05:35:02 PM    15.652
9   08/20/14 06:05:02 PM    14.649
10  08/20/14 06:35:02 PM    13.906
11  08/20/14 07:05:02 PM    13.209
12  08/20/14 07:35:02 PM    12.316
13  08/20/14 08:05:02 PM    12.268
14  08/20/14 08:35:02 PM    12.243
15  08/20/14 09:05:02 PM    12.219
16  08/20/14 09:35:02 PM    12.171
17  08/20/14 10:05:02 PM    12.147
18  08/20/14 10:35:02 PM    12.122
19  08/20/14 11:05:02 PM    12.074
20  08/20/14 11:35:02 PM    12.025
21  08/21/14 12:05:02 AM    11.977
22  08/21/14 12:35:02 AM    11.929
23  08/21/14 01:05:02 AM    11.856
24  08/21/14 01:35:02 AM    11.807
25  08/21/14 02:05:02 AM    11.759
```

and these are the commands:

> class(Noble2$Time)
>   [1] "character"

the csv file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lljwadmnp9uvot/Noble2.csv?dl=0

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You should at least create a little example and post it as part of your question. It is too hard to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x1<-read.csv("Noble2.csv",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # `stringsAsFactors` converts time variable to character before conversion. 
 str(x1)
'data.frame':   7633 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Time: chr  "08/20/14 02:05:02 PM" "08/20/14 02:35:02 PM" "08/20/14 03:05:02 PM" "08/20/14 03:35:02 PM" ...
 $ Temp: num  17 16.7 17 16.8 17 ..

kk<-strptime(x1$Time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")
> str(kk)
 POSIXlt[1:7633], format: "2014-08-20 14:05:02" "2014-08-20 14:35:02" "2014-08-20 15:05:02" "2014-08-20 15:35:02" ...
```

Comment: I used: strptime(Noble2$Time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p"); %I to state it's 0-12 h and %p to state the AM/PM nature of the time. However, the class did not change: > class(Noble2$Time)
[1] "character"

Comment: can you dput the data frame as `dput(Noble)` for your sample data and add in the question?

Comment: couldn't find out how to add it that way, Metrics. Added a dropbox link...  Is it good enough? Sorry and thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you very much, Metrics. I'll have to "investigate" your answer to get to my final goal of plotting 3 files like that one. But, if I am understanding it right, the times will no longer be related with the temperatures in a data.frame, right?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Thank you although I am sure tomorrow I'll have another question to add to this ;)

Comment: So, I better put my question straight away. The part of converting the class into time is done. But it's not on a data.frame format. How can I plot Temp. Vs Time now and in a way I could bring two other data frames of the same type (with different times though) into the same graphic?

Comment: for this example: that will be `plot(kk,x1$Time)`.

Comment: Using your command I'll get this graph: http://127.0.0.1:37389/graphics/plot_zoom_png?width=1200&height=797  using the command    plot(kk,Noble2$Temp, type = "l")  I get this graph  http://127.0.0.1:37389/graphics/plot_zoom_png?width=1200&height=797  None of these graphics make sense with the data I have - on the first, there are several values of temperature appointed to the same time; on the second, there should be one continuous line, not a mix of lines going back and forth. If you could point me in the right direction, also considering that I want to add 2 more data.frames to the graph

Comment: the graphs are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nsfmqjd3zflav5l/Rplot_dots.jpeg?dl=0  https://www.dropbox.com/s/t94bsvlv6lb3rpg/Rplot_lines.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Start from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814216/error-message-plotting-timeseries-with-ggplot2